# How to fix "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ... : Didn't find Class" error?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, runtime-error, classnotfoundexception

I've been trying to install the lingdx engine into the eclipse and open the default android program (with the red background) on my device. The connection is successful but the App closes itself immediately and I get the "RuntimeException ... Didn't find path" error. I've searched that error in google but I couldn't find my error. Where did I do wrong?

Log File:

```
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521): Process: com.mygdx.gameee, PID: 521
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mygdx.gameee/com.mygdx.gameee.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mygdx.gameee.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.gameee-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mygdx.gameee-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.mygdx.gameee-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2868)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1659)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mygdx.gameee.AndroidLauncher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mygdx.gameee-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mygdx.gameee-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.mygdx.gameee-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2858)
05-12 16:36:27.625: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  ... 9 more
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mygdx.gameee" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" /> 

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mygdx.gameee.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

User Android Studio and not Eclipse. Eclipse is not supported for Android development.

Comment: Eclipse is supported for Android Dev.

Comment: Please tell me a valid source for this.

Comment: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/android-development-tools-eclipse . Now tell me where it says it doesn't.

Comment: That's the plugin Google deprecated years ago. I asked for a valid source, a first-hand documentation.

Comment: Really? Deprecated years ago? "Date Updated: 
Mon, 2019-02-04 13:50" Show me where it says that Eclipse is no longer supported.